# Webshell upload in django webapp

Tags: python, django, shell, rce

What file can be uploaded on a webapp built on django framework if it's allowing unrestricted file upload? When I uploaded a shell.py it simply rendered as text in the browser but html and javascript are executing fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you can execute that file when django render, maybe you can try first a `os.system("whoami")`  and then you can change that for a cmd and pass commands  calling that file on your browser/burp/curl. if accept any file, it's really easy

Comment: What extension should the file be? .py?

Comment: in this case .py because you need to do :

`import os

os.system("whoami")`